# MicrobiotaProcess package - error Can't subset columns that don't exist. Column `node` doesn't exist

Tags: r

Please, help.

When performing a microbiome analysis (16s rRNA sequencing data) using the MicrobiotaProcess package (by tutorial: https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/MicrobiotaProcess/inst/doc//MicrobiotaProcess.html) in the "The visualization of taxonomy abundance" and "Biomarker discovery" parts of analysis error occurs.

Phyloseq object was converted to MPSE via as.MPSE(). before analysis

I can not calculate and plot the composition of species communities

While running:

mpse %<>%
mp_cal_abundance( # for each samples
.abundance = RareAbundance
) %>%
mp_cal_abundance( # for each groups
.abundance=RareAbundance,
.group=Group_ons
)

Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `node` doesn't exist.**